# New to matrices need help

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to solve this system of equations by using augmented matrices but I keep getting stuck can any one help me understand it better?

\begin{cases}
3x-2y+5z=-14\\
 x+5y-3z=18\\
-2x-3y+8z=-8
\end{cases}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to begin with, second then first then third,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 5 & -3 & 18 \\
3 & -2 & 5 & -14 \\
-2 & -3 & 8 & -8
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 5 & -3 & 18 \\
0 & -17 & 14 & -68 \\
0 & 7 & 2 & 28
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 5 & -3 & 18 \\
0 & -34 & 28 & -136 \\
0 & 35 & 10 & 140
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 5 & -3 & 18 \\
0 & 1 & 38 & 4 \\
0 & 35 & 10 & 140
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 5 & -3 & 18 \\
0 & 1 & 38 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & -1320 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and so on

Comment: To a matrix newbie, the operations of each transformation would be helpful.

Comment: When row 2 went from (-34 28|-136) to (1 38|4) what row operation did you use? P.S. Thank you a lot this helps a lot.

Comment: @EricO'Brien added row 3 onto row 2